# How to notify a Swift UI view after a coordinator handles delegate call?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a class `MyCoordinator` which implements `SomeDelegate`:

```
class MyCoordinator: NSObject {
    
}

extension MyCoordinator: SomeDelegate {
    func didReceiveSomeData(someData: SomeData) {
        //...someData is needed for the MyControllerRepresantable
    }
}
```

In a `BasicView`, I need to start `MyControllerRepresantable` (which is a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`) with the received data:

```
struct BasicView: View {
//...
    var body: some View { 
//...
        NavigationLink(destination: MyControllerRepresantable(data: someData), isActive: $isNavActive) {}
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to do it ? Maybe I could somehow observe someData so that when it is set, the View gets notified and can access it?

Answer (score 0):

you can store your `View` instance in your `Coordinator` and then notify your view by setting a `Binding` or calling a method.

```
class Coordinator: NSObject {
        let controllerRepresantable: MyControllerRepresantable

        init(_ controllerRepresantable: MyControllerRepresantable) {
            self.controllerRepresantable = controllerRepresantable
        }
```

now you can notify your controllerRepresantable using a callback method or a binding.